# excel to JSON file using python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, openpyxl

I'm having a excel file which contains table names(in a column) and it's schema's in **JSON format**(in adjacent column).

[image: excel file]

Now I need to copy the existing JSON formatted text to a file and save it with a name as respective table names with extension ".json"

like `AAA.json`, `BBB.json` and so on.

I tried this:

```py
import os
import openpyxl

file_name=[]
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/tamil/downloads/Schema_update_Tracker.xlsx')

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('osiris')

start_row = 2
end_row = 136
start_col = 2
end_col = 2

for row in range(start_row, end_row+1):
    cell_value = sheet.cell(row=row, column=2).value
    file_name.append(cell_value)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/tamil/downloads/Schema_update_Tracker.xlsx')

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('osiris')

for i in file_name:
    for row in sheet.rows:
        row_data = {}
  
        for cell in row:
            row_data= cell.value

        data = row_data
        with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
          f.write(data)

new_name = i&".json"
os.rename('data.json', new_name)
```

Results in the following error:

```
File "c:/Users/tamil/OneDrive/Desktop/G/trail.py", line 43, in <module>
    f.write(data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

Comment: hint:with this line inside for loop, `row_data= cell.value` you are overwriting row_data every time

Comment: If `cell.value` is ever `None` you will get this exception. Looks, however, like you want to group the data by row.